# Let $A=\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{5^{i}}:a_i=0,1,2,3$ or $4 \} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then which of the following are true??

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $$A=\bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{5^{i}}\ :\  a_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\} \bigg\} \subset \mathbb{R}.$$ Then which of the following are true:

a. $A$ is a finite set.

b. $A$ is countably infinite.

c. $A$ is uncountable but does not contain an open interval.

d. $A$ contains an open interval.

Each such series is convergent. I could also prove that $A$ is uncountable. I am not able to prove or disprove d.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: These are just the real numbers in $[0,1]$ written in base $5$.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is it like $a_1=0$ , $a_2=1$ etc?

Comment: @Quintic $a_i$ can be anything

Comment: But you wrote $a_i \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: @Quintic I mean it is not necessary for $a_i$ to be all the same. That is $a_i$ and $a_j$ can be different for $i\ne j$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The elements of A amount to all numbers contained in the interval [0,1), where the numbers are expressed in base 5 instead of the usual base 10. Do you see it?